# LEFT JOIN Not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, left-join

I need some help with `LEFT Join`

**first db is "fpo"**

id----empnum-----amount---date----ponum

**second db is "users"**

id----amount-----empid----username----password

I need to total the "amount" in fpo for each user and compare the total to the amount from users.

This is the code i have now that is NOT working.

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,
 "select fpo.amount , fpo.empnum , user.amount , user.fpo SUM(amount) 
  FROM LEFT JOIN fpo ON fpo.empnum = users.empnum GROUP BY empnum");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['empnum'];
  echo "<br>";
  echo $row['amount'];
}
```

For some reason this is not working.... What am i doing wrong i have never worked with JOIn command.

Here is what the data looks like in mysql

```
**first db is "fpo"**
id----empnum-----amount-----date-------ponum
1-----854245-----5.00------9/7/14------12345
2-----123987-----8.00------9/7/14------12345
3-----123987-----5.00------9/7/14------12345
4-----854245-----15.00-----9/7/14------12345
5-----548798-----10.00-----9/7/14------12345
6-----854245-----30.00-----9/7/14------12345

**second db is "users"**
id----amount-----empid----username----password
1-----700.00-----854245---admin-------abc123
2-----500.00-----123987---admin-------abc123
3-----200.00-----548798---admin-------abc123
```

What i am trying to do is `sum(amount)` From fpo where empnum (note:from fpo) = empnum (note:from users)
then echo the summed amount with the empnumber and the amount from the users table.

I need to do this for everyone in the users db. I have about 150 people in there right now.....

Thank you for your time and help!!! Probably a simple problem :(

Comment: You're missing a comma before `SUM(amount)`. Try checking for errors from `mysqli_query()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not echoing the summed amount, `$row['amount']` is the amount of a single row, you want `$row['SUM(amount)']`. I suggest you give it an alias to make it easier to access:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select f.amount , u.empid , u.amount , 
                                u.fpo, SUM(u.amount) AS total
                             FROM users AS u
                             LEFT JOIN fpo AS f ON f.empnum = u.empid
                             GROUP BY u.empid") or die(mysqli_error($con));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo $row['empnum'];
      echo "<br>";
      echo $row['total'];
}
```

You were also missing the comma before `SUM(amount)`, the table name after `FROM`, and you need to qualify `amount` with the table name because both tables have a column named `amount`. You also had `user.empnum` in your `ON` clause, but that column is `users.empid`.

You should select and group by the column from `users`, not `fpo`, because `LEFT JOIN` can return rows where the columns from `fpo` are `NULL` if there's no match for `users.empid`.

Comment: still not working.....<pre>$result = mysqli_query($con,"select fpo.amount , fpo.empnum , user.amount , 
                                user.fpo, SUM(amount) AS total
                             FROM users
                             LEFT JOIN fpo ON fpo.empnum = users.empnum 
                             GROUP BY empnum");
      
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo $row['empnum'];
      echo "<br>";
      echo $row['total'];
}</pre>

Comment: Have you looked at the error message from MySQL? There's no `users.empnum`, it's `users.empid`.

Comment: Thank you didnt know that. My bad that was my typing error it is empnum NOT empid the error code is Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home1/public_html/tck/admin/usage.php on line 202 ----- line 202 is the WHILE()

Comment: What is the mysql error printed by `or die(mysqli_error()`?

Comment: i have `ini_set('display_errors',1);  
error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the start of my document. Thats whats displaying the code.

Comment: That doesn't display the SQL errors. You have to call `mysqli_error()`, like I do in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62379/discussion-between-kelly-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me.  Thanks!

```
    result = mysqli_query($con,"select f.amount , u.empnum , u.amount , 
                                SUM(f.amount) AS total
                             FROM users AS u
                             LEFT JOIN fpo AS f ON f.empnum = u.empnum
                             GROUP BY u.empnum")

                              or die(mysqli_error($con));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "Emp".$row['empnum']."----".$row['total']."----Amount----".$row['amount']."<br>";
```